# Better to apply controller through ng-app directive or .config controller property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any pros or cons to how I apply a controller to a document/element, either by using:

`ng-controller="appCtrl"` with-in the HTML

*OR*

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/document.htm',
        controller: 'appCtrl'        
    })
```

Is it down to personal preference?

Comment: The first one you've put is the 'app', not the controller (that would be ng-controller)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, anything to say to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question. The ng-controller would be the traditional way of putting a controller in perhaps for a particular section of a page in a SPA. So that might be better for a small SPA where you have only one or a few pages/controllers.

The second option you've posted for routes, where you have many pages and you want to use that option for a page controller.

Either can be used, either would work. For organisation's sake I would tend towards the latter only because I'm used to it and use it day in day out.

Comment: Ok then. I wondered whether there was a possibility it helped page load times or something along those lines but I guess not. Thank you for your time!

Comment: AFAIK (and I'm no expert in load times) the straightforward comparison of the two would not be greatly different in load time; if you started adding resolves into your router config, then that might change, the more there are the longer it would take.